# pd.to_numeric is not working in python

Tags: python, pandas, numeric

I'm using Jupyter notebook. Default python kernel. 'numpy' and 'pandas' imported.

This column is named 'Period'. The value contains numbers and text like "Period". The data type is 'object'. I would like to delete the rows in which the value of column 'Period' is not a number. 
What I tried to do is to first convert the column from object to numeric.

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Period'],errors='coerce')
```

It returned a list of numbers and NaNs. The last line lies:

```
Name: Period, dtype: float64
```

If I checked again:

```
df['Period'].dtype
```

It returns:

```
dtype('O')
```

Apparently the converting did not actually work. Also with the following code, it dropped nothing.

```
df.dropna(subset=['Period'])
```

What do you think went wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pandas operations like `to_numeric` don't operate "in-place" by default. I recommend that you assign the result to a column in your dataframe.

`df['Period_numbers'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Period'], errors='coerce')`

Same goes with `dropna`.

In most cases you can pass `inplace=True` to the method or function. But I really do recommend assigning the results instead.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively:

```
df[df['Period'].str.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values